# What time format is the VodaPay API "request-time" header?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

The current toISOString() javascript function does not supply the correct format that is required for the auth/payment flow header "request-time" field. How do I implement the correct format for my API request in JavaScript?

Comment: The Z indicates that the ISO string is the date in UTC time. Have posted answer below on how to convert this to local offset time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the this function that transforms the date to the correct format for your use.

```
function dateToLocalISO(date) { 
    const off    = date.getTimezoneOffset()
    const absoff = Math.abs(off)
    return (new Date(date.getTime() - off*60*1000).toISOString().substr(0,23) +
            (off > 0 ? '-' : '+') + 
            Math.floor(absoff / 60).toFixed(0).padStart(2,'0') + ':' + 
            (absoff % 60).toString().padStart(2,'0'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript to make the requests to the backend server you can also make use of the luxon npm package

```
import {DateTime} from 'luxon';
const requestTime = DateTime.local().toISO();
```

It will provide it in the correct ISO format.
[Luxon Documentation on toISO](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-toISO)